# I want that the user can only type x.x.x.x in a Textbox

Tags: winforms, textbox, maskedtextbox

I want that the user can only type X.X.X.X in a Textbox (X is a number)

I tried a maskedTextbox and changed under properties the mask to:

```
//Mask: 9.9.9.9

//Previw: _,_,_,_
```

but when I got the value out of the maskedTextbox I get:

```
//Value: 1,1,1,1
```

is there a possibility that i can get:

```
//Value : 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: What is your culture settings? Try to set `NumberDecimalSeparator` to dot `.`

Comment: you need a text box that will accept only numbers and dots, isn't it?

Comment: my culture settings : de - At 
@Sujith Karivelil : yes but it has to be in this order: "x.x.x.x"

Comment: I guess you are having culture as nl-NL because it treats . as ,

Comment: no in the properties is culture = de - At

Comment: your culture creating problem because de-At also treats . as ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [documentation for the `Mask` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `.`
>   Decimal placeholder. The actual display character used will be the decimal symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.
>
> ...
>
> `\` Escape. Escapes a mask character, turning it into a literal. "\\" is the escape sequence for a backslash.

So you shouldn't be using `.` if you always want a period regardless of regional settings: you should use `\.` in that case.

Comment: Thanks, i'll set it as "right Answer" but i can't do it now 
(and sry i cant set this answe as usefull because i'm do not have 15 reputation) , have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your culture creating problem as de-At treats `.` as `,` so you need to convert it to "."

try below code :-

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```